# Passing app Id to fb.init() dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am authenticating my asp.net website using facebook and twiiter.
My application is a product ,so  different users having the different App_Id to the authentication.
so i want to pass it dynamically,i fetched the App_Id from the database.
I use the "aspsnippets.facebookapi.dll", using that i can dynamically assign App_Id
as below

```
List<SocialLoginModal> listLoginSocial = new List<SocialLoginModal>();
            listLoginSocial = dalLoginSocial.getBind();
            if (listLoginSocial.Count > 0)
            {
                //FACEBOOK Keys
                List<SocialLoginModal> listFBLogin = new List<SocialLoginModal>();
                listFBLogin = listLoginSocial.Where(x => x.AuthenticationName == "Facebook").ToList();
                if (listFBLogin.Count > 0)
                {
                    FaceBookConnect.API_Key = Convert.ToString(listFBLogin[0].Api_Key);
                    FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = Convert.ToString(listFBLogin[0].Api_Secret);
                    fbId.Value = Convert.ToString(listFBLogin[0].Api_Key);
                }

                //TWITTER Keys
                List<SocialLoginModal> listTwitterLogin = new List<SocialLoginModal>();
                listTwitterLogin = listLoginSocial.Where(x => x.AuthenticationName == "Twiiter").ToList();
                if (listTwitterLogin.Count > 0)
                {
                    TwitterConnect.API_Key = Convert.ToString(listTwitterLogin[0].Api_Key);
                    TwitterConnect.API_Secret = Convert.ToString(listTwitterLogin[0].Api_Secret);
                }
            }
```

and it works fine,
but the problem is it i'll not work with godaddy server .
so i moved to sdk, given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fbId = document.getElementById('<%=fbId.ClientID%>').value;
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk',
            ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement('script');
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

    // Init the SDK upon load
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.init({           
            appId : '273672922689018', // App ID
            channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true // parse XFBML
        });

        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
                FB.api('/me', function(me) {
                    if (me.name) {
                        document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                    }
                })
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
        $("#auth-logoutlink").click(function() {
            FB.logout(function() {
                window.location.reload();
            });
        });
    }
    </script>
```

i tried to pass the value dynamically to appid as below

var fbId = document.getElementById('<%=fbId.ClientID%>').value;

and assign it to app Id as

```
FB.init({           
                appId : fbId , // App ID
                channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true // parse XFBML
            });
```

it dose't work ..
how to pass the app id Dynamically in that place

Answer (score 1):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {  
            FB.init({  
                appId: '<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBsubAppId"] %>', // App ID  
                oauth: true,  
                status: true, // check login status  
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session  
                xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML  
                version: 'v2.0' // New  
            });  
        };
```